# How can I turn on and off a Raspberry Pi with another MCU?

Tags: pi-3

I am currently working on a project that has a ATtiny85 as a secondary microcontroller that is constantly on a low power mode. The plan is when this MCU senses weight from the weight sensor (Force), it would in theory turn on the Raspberry Pi which would then power the whole system and when no weight is sensed turn off the Raspberry Pi.

**I have 2 ideas**

1.) Using an RF signal that would act like a remote?

2.) Using some sort of switch that would turn on and allow power to flow to the RPI?

I have no idea how to actually carry out these ideas but would they even be possible? if so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

**More information:**

Both of these controllers will be powered by a 3.5 V LiPo battery which will probably change after our testing stage. There will be several buck and boost converters for each of the sensors and MCUs. These MCU will also be confined to a small area connected to a carseat.

**The purpose of the RPI**

-to collect data and determine what to do with that information.
-relay information to a user through an app via bluetooth
-determine from the data collected if it is necessary to contact the user or emergency services through SMS and voice call.
-It is complete overkill but was chosen to increase the difficulty of the project.

**Concept of the project**
    Develop a carseat that can determine if a child has been left in the car. It will monitor its temperature and ambient temp until the guardian is able to get back. If the guardian has yet to return to the car and the child is about to enter critical condition the RPI will call emergency services and relay the last known GPS location as well as send several SMS messages to the guardian.

Comment: what is the purpose of the RPi?

Comment: Please merge your accounts to save everyone continued hassles here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you said "Both of these controllers will be powered by a 3.5 V LiPo battery". The raspberry pi needs five volts to run, so you will need a step-up transformer or power source to power the pi.

second, non-safely turning your pi on and off would be very easy -- just run the power cord through a relay(electronically activated switch), then switch the relay on and off. but this has the dangers of damaging your sd card.

Here is my solution for your problem:
(this idea does not actually remove power from the pi, it just shuts it down and turns it back on. you could add a relay to actually remove power, if you wanted.)
you will need one pnp transistor.

my idea is:

you could wire up the pnp transistor to GPIO pin 5 and a pin on the ATtiny85 so when you digitalWrite LOW to that pin on the ATtiny, it shuts the rpi down. for this to work you will need to create a script in your home directory called poweroff.py with these contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.wait_for_edge(5, GPIO.FALLING)

subprocess.call(['shutdown', '-h', 'now'], shell=False)
```

then type `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and add

```
sleep 2
python /home/pi/poweroff.py & 
exit 0
```

to the very bottom of the file. (this will make it automatically run when you turn on the pi. you could alternatively type `sudo nano /etc/profile` and add `sudo python /home/pi/poweroff.py &` to the very bottom, but you would have to enable autologin for this to work.)

this takes care of powering it off. to power it back on, all you have to do is digitalWrite LOW (ground) to gpio pin 3 (physical pin 5).

ps. I am a beginner at stack exchange, so I know this might be a very hard-to-understand (or not well-written) explanation, please let me know any questions in the comments.

[Here's where I got this idea from.](https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi)

Comment: *"this will make it automatically run when you turn on the pi"* -> Only if autologin is enabled, since `/etc/profile` does **not** run at boot, it runs when a user logs in.  Presuming this is a headless system with no interface, there is no reason for anyone to log in or for using autologin.

Comment: Ok. maybe add it to `/etc/rc.local ` then?

Comment: I rewrote it to use a transistor

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is a much better practice.

Comment: I changed it to `rc.local`.